# Visual Studio 2015/2017 +react +typescript

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript

Have anyone found a complete react+typescript-tutorial in Visual Studio 2015/2017 MVC-project that works, from start to finish?

Ive tried to just get the NuGet-packages named "Reactjs Mvc4" and "typescript", created a .tsx-file, and copied some of the .config/package-files(from guide below), but the more I google, the more extra stuff I seem to be needing. In the end gets me different kinds of errors.

[This one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/samples/index.html) seems ok. It does produce all .config/.package-files one the correct locations, but it seems to assume you are using VS Code.

Answer (score -1):

Hi check this cool template its good beginning for react typescript redux and router.

[JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices)

You can generate VisualStudio project.

Form GIT:

JavaScriptServices is a set of client-side technologies for ASP.NET Core. It provides infrastructure that you'll find useful if you:

Use Angular / React / Vue / Aurelia / Knockout / etc.
Build your client-side resources using Webpack.
Execute JavaScript on the server at runtime.
Read Building Single Page Applications on ASP.NET Core with JavaScriptServices for more details.

This repo contains:

A set of NuGet/NPM packages that implement functionality for:
Invoking arbitrary NPM packages at runtime from .NET code (docs)
Server-side prerendering of SPA components (docs)
Webpack dev middleware (docs)
Hot module replacement (HMR) (docs)
Server-side and client-side routing integration (docs)
Server-side and client-side validation integration
"Lazy loading" for Knockout apps
A Yeoman generator that creates preconfigured app starting points (guide)
Samples and docs
It's cross-platform (Windows, Linux, or macOS) and works with .NET Core 1.0.1 or later.